# How to remove edges around header in CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout, margins

I have this weird border all around my header:

[image]

It's written in html and css, the relevant source code is below:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Killa Media</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="https://killa-media.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Killa_logo.png" alt="Killa Media icon logo"> </a>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-links"> 
                <li><a href="/about/" class="nav-item">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="/services/" class="nav-item">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact/" class="nav-item">GET IN TOUCH</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>  
    </header>
```

CSS:
[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks.

I've tried using -10 margins, but that didn't work properly.
I thought 100% width would fix this, it didn't.

Comment: have you tried `body { margin: 0 }`

Comment: You are asking a CSS question and you haven't included any CSS code.  Please post the actual code as text and not a picture of the code.

Comment: I'm such an idiot, sorry. I forgot about the body margin 0.

Comment: I wasn't able to upload the css as text, stack overflow said that I had more code than text and that's not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Using **CSS Reset**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }
```

This will remove ***padding*** and ***margin*** from all elements.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you probably have either too much margin or padding.
Here is what I recommend:

```
body{
margin: 0px;
}
```